# Undefined when trying to use Spy

Tags: node.js, sinon

Using my code:

```
    it('should start application only once', function(done){
        var spy = sinon.spy(server, 'startup');

        var calledOnce = spy().calledOnce;

        calledOnce.should.be.true;

        done();
    });
```

I get the error:

> Cannot read property should of undefined.

The `calledOnce` variable is undefined.  I'm doing something wrong in how I setup the spy and use it.  How can I fix this?

Startup is a method in my object that I exported from a server.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if a particular function/method has been called, you need to spy on it *before* it gets called (otherwise the spy won't know about it):

```
var server = ...
var spy    = sinon.spy(server, 'startup');

server.startup(...);

spy.calledOnce.should.be.true;
```